# Freemarker - How to indirectly recognize a missing list

Tags: freemarker

In Freemarker, how can I indirectly identify a missing list variable?  By indirectly, I mean that I have a string value containing the name of the list;  I need to convert that string to a variable name (of the list) and then check to see if the list is present.  This indirection is critical to my application.

For example, this code works:

```
<#assign existing_list      = ["a","b"]>
<#assign existing_list_name = "existing_list">
<#assign ref_existing_list  = existing_list_name?eval>

<#if ref_existing_list?has_content>
    Correctly identified existing list.
<#else>
    Failed to identify existing list.
</#if>
```

producing output:

```
 Correctly identified existing list.
```

But if the list is not present, then I cannot convert the string to a variable name to check if the list is present.  For example:

```
<#assign nonexistent_list_name = "nonexistent_list">
<#assign ref_nonexistent_list  = nonexistent_list_name?eval>

<#if ref_nonexistent_list?has_content>
    Failed to identify that list was non-existent.
<#else>
    Correctly identified that list was non-existent.
</#if>
```

aborts Freemarker with the following error:

```
<FreeMarker>[Error] freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following  has evaluated to null or missing:
==> nonexistent_list_name?eval  [in template "utilities\\mhc\\templates\\app\\app.h.ftl" at line 17, column 34]
```

It would seem like I need the capability to either convert a string to a variable name even if the variable is missing, or else execute eval on a null variable reference without aborting.  But I have not been able to find either of those Freemarker capabilities.

Can anyone propose a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to realize here is that you can't assign missing things to variables. But you can do these:

```
<#assign nonexistent_list_name = "nonexistent_list">

<#if .vars[nonexistent_list_name]?has_content>
  The list exists AND is not empty
<#else>
  The list doesn't exists OR it's empty
</#if>

<#-- The above is nicer, but this still works: -->
<#if nonexistent_list_name?eval?has_content>
  The list exists AND is not empty
<#else>
  The list doesn't exists OR it's empty
</#if>
```

Another thing that's good to know is that `?has_content` gives `false` for existing but empty lists. If you only wanted to check if the list exists, then use `??` instead (like `<#if .vars[nonexistent_list_name]??>`). But if you indeed want to treat empty and missing lists the same way, then, after all, you can do the assignment too:

```
<#assign nonexistent_list_name = "nonexistent_list">
<#assign nonexistent_listref = .vars[nonexistent_list_name]!>

<#if nonexistent_listref?has_content>
  The list exists AND is not empty
<#else>
  The list doesn't exists OR it's empty
</#if>
```

(Note that `#list` can have an `#else` branch for empty lists, which can save some characters when you want to do a listing anyway.)

Comment: Excellent advice!  That indeed worked.  Thank you very much for your help.